# logic to distribute 8 ldap sever evenly to 24k vms

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking idea about evenly distributing 8 ldap server to 24k machine,i.e 3k vm to each one server but how to do it in one command?
each client vm name end with 0..9, could be any logic where I can use i.e all 1,2,3 ending vms to server1 and 4,5,6 to server2 and so on?
its for slapd.conf
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question is too broad and unclear.